# Uniformly bounded metric

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $(V,g)$ be a globally hyperbolic manifold of the type $S \times \mathbb{R}$, where $S$ is an oriented smooth manifold, $g$ is pseudo-Riemannian with signature $(-,+,...,+)$  and each submanifold $S \times \{t\}$ is spacelike. $g$ is defined to be of the form

$$g=-N^2dt^2+ \sigma_{ij}\theta^i \theta^j, \ \theta^i= dx^i+ \beta^i dt$$

where the scalar function $N$ is strictly positive and $\sigma_t$ is Riemannian on each $S_t$ and $\sigma_t$ uniformly equivalent to a complete metric $e$.

In "Wave maps in general relativity", the is a theorem, stating a local existence result for wave maps on $V$:

Suppose $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$, $(M,h)$ a Riemannian manifold. A mapping $u: V \rightarrow M$ is then
globally defined by a set of $m$ scalar functions $u^A$ on $V$.
Suppose the metric $h$ is smooth. Suppose $g$ is smooth **with uniformly bounded
derivatives of arbitrary order with respect to** $t$ and $e$, i.e., $N$, $\beta$, $g$ possess these
properties. Let $\varphi^A \in C^0_b$, $D \varphi^A \in H_{s-1}$, and $\psi \in H_{s-1}$ be Cauchy data such that $s > \dfrac{n}{2}+1$.

Then there exists a wave map on $S \times [0,T)$....

I don't really understand the condition " **with uniformly bounded
derivatives of arbitrary order with respect to**" since I don't understand how to "measure" the metric. Isn't it always dependent of the coordinate chart? Also, what does uniformly bounded mean here?

My only idea: for an atlas, one can view the union of $g_{ij}$ for all charts as a family of smooth functions and using the supremum norm, on could obtain a uniform bound. Is that the correct idea?

Comment: Good question. Is $g$ the hyperbolic metric itself or a different one. If the latter, you can measure $g$ relative to the hyperbolic metric.

Comment: As far as I see, $g$ is defined to be the hyperbolic metric itself.

Comment: Perhaps you could state the theorem and maybe other relevant language?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: The full statements clarify what's going on. A crucial part of the sentence is "with respect to $t$ and $e$". $e$ is apparently a fixed complete metric on the manifold. We often call such a metric a "background metric". So "uniformly bounded derivatives" of the metric $g$ means the covariant derivatives of $g$ with respect to the metric $e$ are uniformly bounded. Your idea of using coordinate charts is equivalent.

Comment: I don't really understand this yet. Is it correct that you mean the family of functions $e(g(t,.), g(t,.))$ is uniformly bounded? If that is the case, what if $g=-dt^2+ e$, so that $\sigma_t$ is not only uniformly equivalent to $e$ but is $e$ itself.  Then $e(g(t,.), g(t,.))$ doesn't make sence.

Comment: Here's one way to put it: $e$ is a Riemannian metric and therefore defines a pointwise norm on tensors. Its Levi-Civita connection defines covariant derivatives of tensors up to any order. Therefore, since $g$ is a tensor, the metric $e$ defines a norm on $g$ and its covariant derivatives up to any order.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't really understand you. If $g$ is defined through $e$, isn't it then the same as measuring a metric by itself?

Comment: But you said that my idea is equivalent?